# Proper REST formatted URL with date ranges

Tags: rest

I have a REST URL to get all users formatted like this:
    http://example.com/users

To get an individual user by id:
    http://example.com/users/12345

To get all user's bids:
    http://example.com/users/12345/bids

To get all user's bids between two dates:
    http://example.com/users/12345/bids/?start=01/01/2012&end=01/31/2012

or should it be like this:
    http://example.com/users/12345/bids/start/01012012/end/01312012

I'm leaning towards the 1st date range URL as start and end are not entities in the domain. What is the proper way to format a REST URL with a date range?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I would suggest putting the dates in ISO 8061 format: 2012-01-31. This avoids uncertainty about whether it's month-day-year or day-month-year.

Comment: If you use the path separator `/` to delimit the values you're likely to encounter numerous issues. If you decide you want the start and end dates to allow ISO formats e.g. `2021-10-12T01:00:00.000Z`, `2021-10-01T18:00:00.000+05:00`, those formats contain characters that will break the URL. Much better to use querystring parameters

Answer (score 88, accepted):

http://example.com/users/12345/bids?start=01-01-2012&end=01-31-2012

Have the query parameters on the same "level" as the bids (remove the slash before the question mark). But you would probably want to have support for if they only provide one query parameter. So if they only provided "start" then it would get all bids after that date, or if they only provided "end" it would get all bids before that date.

The reasoning being that query parameters are good for GETting a subset of results from a GET request. They don't go on another level because the next level is usually one specific item with a unique identifier.

Comment: blog posts and senior colleagues I think? I probably shouldn't have been answering StackOverflow questions straight out of college, but I guess it worked out.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, it might help if you could add some guidelines/documentation  or good reads on the topic :)

Answer (score 17):

I would go with `http://example.com/users/12345/bids?start=2012-01-01&end=2012-01-31`.

- There shouldn't be a slash before the query string.
- Avoid using slashes in the query string. It'll be easier that way.

Comment: well then one should probably also use an internationally readable date format, which would be `2012-01-31` according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601. `MDY` is literally USA-only ..... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Answer (score 3):

If you use the path separator `/` to delimit the values you're likely to encounter numerous issues. If you decide you want the start and end dates to allow ISO formats e.g. `2021-10-12T01:00:00.000Z`, `2021-10-01T18:00:00.000+05:00`, those formats contain characters that will break the URL. Much better to use querystring parameters.

I'd recommend using the querystring and ISO format for dates so your URL will look something like this:

https://example.com/users/12345/bids?start=2022-08-08T00:00:00.000Z&end=2022-08-09T00:00:00.000Z

Your API method that retrieves by date range can then be differentiated from the GET request that retrieves *all* bids for the user, simply by using a different method signature that expects additional `start` and `end` date parameters in the request.

Answer (score 1):

if example.com/users/12345 gets the user with id 12345, then to get all users by id it should be  example.com/users with the id included in the response as a relationship. (usually a hyperlink to that resource).

Now to get them by date ranges it should be example.com/users/start=01-01-2012&end=01-31-2012

The 12345 part is the id of an individual user, it's a resource, therefore it should not be included to get the rest of the users.

As the name of the parameter it should be meaningful. start could mean anything, but start_date is more meaninful.