# filter search 2 date range In laravel 5.2

Tags: search, filter, laravel-5

how  too make filter search 2 date range?example: view date_first until date_last, in laravel 5.2

Sorry my english is poor
Please, help me to resolved this problem

Comment: What have you already tried? Share the query you're using.

Comment: There is an answer for a similar question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637297/proper-rest-formatted-url-with-date-ranges