# How to get Swagger UI to display similar Spring Boot REST endpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have a controller class with two endpoints

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping(
          value= "/test",
          method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String getTest() {
    return "test without params";
  }

  @RequestMapping(
          value= "/test",
          params = {"param"},
          method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String getTest(@PathParam("param") int param) {
    return "test with param";
  }

}
```

One has a parameter, one doesn't, and the both work.

If I use curl or a web browser to hit the endpoints

> http://localhost:8081/test

returns

> test without params

and

> http://localhost:8081/test?param=1

returns

> test with param

but the swagger ui only shows the one without a parameter.

If I change the value in the request mapping for the request with a parameter to

```
  @RequestMapping(
          value= "/testbyparam",
          params = {"param"},
          method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Swagger UI displays both endpoints correctly, but I'd rather not define my endpoints based on what swagger will or won't display.

Is there any way for me to get swagger ui to properly display endpoints with matching values, but different parameters?

Edit for Clarification:

The endpoints work perfectly fine; /test and /test?param=1 both work perfectly, the issue is that swagger-ui won't display them.

I would like for swagger ui to display the endpoints I have defined, but if it can't, then I'll just have to live with swagger-ui missing some of my endpoints.

Edit with reference:

The people answering here: [Proper REST formatted URL with date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637297/proper-rest-formatted-url-with-date-ranges)

explicitly say not to seperate the query string with a slash

They also said "There shouldn't be a slash before the query string."

Comment: While *Spring* can handle these two request mappings, *Swagger* still finds them ambiguous and will display only of them. Spring has only been able to handle those recently, if I'm remembering correctly (but I work with a wide variety of spring versions so I could be wrong.)

Comment: Wait, i'm sorry can you please clarify what you want. Are you expecting QUERY PARAMS (which you stated) or PATH PARAMS(which you've coded)

query param: GET /test  and GET /test?param=1
path param: GET /test and GET /test/1

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding the distinction between the two, but it sounds like I want path parameters.  What I've coded is what I want; the endpoints I have are the ones I want to keep.  If Roddy of the Frozen Peas is correct, and this is a current limitation of Swagger, then I'll stick with the current path variables, and stop worrying about Swagger.

Comment: A path parameter shows up in the URL path: 
/test/123
a query parameter shows up in the query string: /test?param=123. 

The code you provided above uses `@PathParam` which is a path parameter, but your description refers to QUERY parameters (which would use `@RequestParam`. please clarify the behaviour you expect

Comment: This matters because what you're tryign to do is possible with path parameters, `/test` and `/test/123` are distinct routes but not with query parameters though there is a cleaner way to do them than what you have above.

Comment: I think what I want is path paramaters, unless he's wrong; at https://medium.com/@moschan/when-should-you-use-path-variable-and-query-parameter-a346790e8a6d he says "If you want to identify a resource, you should use Path Variable. But if you want to sort or filter items, then you should use query parameter." ...

Comment: I want my variables identifiable in my path.  I posted the current working endpoints in the question; that's the behaviour I want.  Right now, in the example I have http://localhost:8081/test and http://localhost:8081/test?param=1; in my actual application it's more like http://localhost:8081/test http://localhost:8081/test?id=1 and http://localhost:8081/test?start=somedate&stop=someotherdate

Comment: I also faced the same problem as well. It looks like the swagger account the method + rest-path url as one. It is a bug in swagger.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your Request Mapping, The second method declaration is overriding the first method. As Resource Mapping value is same.

Try changing the second method to below. As you want to give input in QueryParam rather than path variable, you should use @RequestParam not @PathParam.

Note that you have to give /test/, In order to tell Spring that your mapping is not ambiguous. Hope it helps.

```
@RequestMapping(
          value= "/test/",
          method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String getTest (@RequestParam("param") int param) {
    return "test with param"+param;
  }
```

Comment: That's not the mapping I want though.

Comment: Hit enter too soon, I'll finish below.

Comment: Right now the endpoints for /test and /test?param=1 both work, the issue is that swagger-ui doesn't show both of them.  I don't want the endpoint /test/param= in fact, there are other REST questions on here where the answers said not the split the parameter like that.

Comment: The people answering at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637297/proper-rest-formatted-url-with-date-ranges said not seperate the query string witha  slash

Comment: Damien , I have made changes according to your requirements, this holds all the purpose, You can have request like this http://localhost:8080/product/test/?param=1.

Comment: I have working endpoints http://localhost:8081/test and http://localhost:8081/test?param=1 the issue is that swagger ui isn't displaying them, but I cans still hit them with curl, or in a browser and they work fine.  The issue with http://localhost:8081/test/?param=1 is that all the advice I can find on the subject, says not to seperate the path parameters with a slash like that.  The answers in the question I linked specifically said not to do that. "There shouldn't be a slash before the query string."

Comment: There is no difference between , http://localhost:8080/test?param=1 and
http://localhost:8080/test/?param=1. HTTP just ignore the '/' before the ?. API will work with both the URLs

Comment: Answers you are referring suggesting that not to use '/' before query string while making rest requests, because its easier that way. you can use  localhost:8080/test?param=1  url by implementing above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178142/discussion-between-mohit-sharma-and-damien).

Answer (score 0):

Upon reading clarifications, the issue here is that swagger-ui is doing the correct thing.

You have two controller endpoints, but they are for the same RESOURCE `/test` that takes a set of optional query parameters.

Effectively, all mapped controller endpoints that have the same method (`GET`) and request mapping (`/test`) represent a single *logical* resource. GET operation on the `test` resource, and a set of optional parameters which may affect the results of invoking that operation.

The fact that you've implemented this as two separate controller endpoints is an implementation detail and does not change the fact that there is a single `/test` resource that can be operated upon.

What would be the benefit to consumers of your API by listing this as two separate endpoints in swagger UI vs a single endpoint with optional parameters? Perhaps it could constrain the set of allowed valid query parameters (if you set `?foo` you MUST set `&bar`) but this can also be done in descriptive text, and is a much more standard approach. Personally, I am unfamiliar with any publicly documented api that distinguishes multiple operations for the same resource differentiated by query params.

Answer (score 0):

As per Open API Specification 3

> OpenAPI defines a unique operation as a combination of a path and an
> HTTP method. This means that two GET or two POST methods for the same
> path are not allowed – even if they have different parameters
> (parameters have no effect on uniqueness).

Reference - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

This was also raised as an issue but it was closed because OAS3 doesn't allow that -
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/859

Answer (score -1):

I'm unclear exactly what you're attempting to do, but I'll give two solutions:

If you want to have PATH parameters e.g. `GET /test` & `GET /test/123` you can do:

```
  @GetMapping("/test")
  public String getTest() {
    return "test without params";
  }

  @GetMapping("test/{param}")
  public String getTest(@PathVariable("param") int param) {
    return "test with param";
  }
```

If you want query parameters (`GET /test` and `GET /test?param=123`) then you need a single endpoint that takes an optional parameter:

```
  @GetMapping("test")
  public String getTest(@RequestParam("param") Integer param) {
    if(param == null) { 
      return "test without params";
    } else {
      return "test with param";
    }
  }
```

Comment: also another note: you're using `@RestController` and thus there is no need to annotation your class with `@RequestMapping` nor to annotate your methods with `@ResponseBody`

Comment: Thanks for the advice on removing the unnexxessary annotations, less clutter is good.  My endpoints work perfectly fine as is; the issue is that swagger doesn't recognize them, but if I have to drop swagger, I can.  I was trying to follow the advice here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637297/proper-rest-formatted-url-with-date-ranges the answers said not to split the query string with a slash.

Comment: Your query parameters would not have a slash in this case, you're splitting your PATH parameters with the slash, not your QUERY parameters. My assumption is that whatever you're using to generate your swagger does not recognize that the two methods in your original question represent different flavors of the endpoint because the path in them is exactly the same.

Comment: Both of the answers there say the same thing "There shouldn't be a slash before the query string."  Are they wrong, or does it not apply in my case.  In my actual code, I have a lot more that just the two endpoints, and a lot more possible queries, one being id, another being a date range like in the question I linked.

Comment: GetMapping doesn't seem to work the way you're suggesting; swagger-ui builds this Curl command for it.  curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: text/plain' -d '1234' 'http://localhost:8081/test//{param}'

Comment: Well it's not that the `@GetMapping` doesn't work... it's whatever you are using to generate your swagger specification FROM the mappings. Are you using Springfox?

Comment: Yep springfox.  These are the compile lines from my build.gradle     compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.7.0'

Comment: Your second one is the result I want, but it's functionally identical to what I have, and won't scale well without a bit of ugliness to the number of endpoints I actually have.  It retains the problem that I'm trying to solve.  My endpoints work exactly as I want them to; the issue is that swagger ui doesn't recognize them all, your example has the same issue, my two endpoints are represented in swagger as one.  As Roddy said, this looks like it might be a limitation of Swagger.

Comment: If you're talking query parameters they _are_ one endpoint. They _should_ be represented as one endpoint - with an optional parameter

Answer (score -1):

Try including the param in the path as below.

```
@GetMapping("/test/{param}")
public String getTest(@PathVariable final int param) {
    return "test with param";
}
```

Comment: The endpoints I have work; the issue is that swagger ui isn't recognizing them all.  I was trying to follow the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637297/proper-rest-formatted-url-with-date-ranges the people answering there said not to split the query string with a slash like you're doing.

Comment: Have you tried making this change and verified the swagger ui again? Swagger should display it as two different end points - /test, /test/{param}. BTW, param is a path variable, not query param.

Comment: BTW, swagger UI is correct to group the URLs under one end point if the difference is only in query params. Consider an example of an api for managing users, /users is one end point which you can use to list down all users, and different query params can be applied to filter it (e.g. name). In this case there could be more than one result and hence the return value is going to be collection. But if you want to look up the user using the unique id, then use the id in path param /users/{id} and it will return only one result. Swagger UI will display these end points as /users, and /users/{id}.